# Sheet name already exists, how to handle the error and delete the default sheet in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Creating a sheet with a name from sheet1 works great. However, if I mistakenly run the code again, it gives runtime 1004 error, because the newly created sheet name already exists. This is fine, but how can I handle this error and prevent Excel from creating one default sheet with a random name?

I want Excel to MsgBox me that there is a duplicate and it should then do nothing. I know there are similar threads, but they didn't answer my question. Thanks.

```
Private Sub CreateSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             Worksheets("Sheet1"))

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ws.Name = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1")

    On Error Resume Next

    If (Worksheets("ws.Name").Name <> "") Then

    MsgBox ("name already exists, please delete")

    Else

    ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:AB").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: do you need the "ws.name" in "'s?  you're looking for a sheet called ws.name not the value of ws.name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other way to check if a sheet exists is a loop which some people prefer instead of `On Error ...`

```
 Public Function sheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional wrkBook As Workbook) As Boolean

    If wrkBook Is Nothing Then
        Set wrkBook = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook - whichever appropriate
    End If

    On Error GoTo EH

    sheetExists = False  ' Not really neccessary as this is the default

    Dim sht As Object

    For Each sht In wrkBook.Sheets
        If Ucase(sht.Name) = UCase(SheetName) Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sht

    Exit Function

EH:
    sheetExists = False
End Function
```

Then you could rewrite your sub like that

```
Private Sub CreateSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim newName As String
    newName = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1")

    If sheetExists(newName, ThisWorkbook) Then
        MsgBox ("name already exists, please delete")
    Else
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
            Worksheets("Sheet1"))

        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        ws.Name = newName

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:AB").Copy
        ws.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: holy cow, this works perfectly. The beautiful part about this is that you have a reusable function for any other purposes. Very cool, thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

You can create a custom function and test it in your code before running the sheet creation code like...

```
Public Function SheetExists(WkBkName As String, ShtName As String) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = Application.Workbooks(WkBkName).Worksheets(ShtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If sht Is Nothing Then
        SheetExists = False
    Else
        SheetExists = True
    End If
End Function
```

And then you can use this UDF in code like below...

```
Sub Test()
    If SheetExists(ThisWorkbook.Name, "Sheet2") Then
        MsgBox "Sheet Exists!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Sheet Doesn't Exist!"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Yours works of course as well. I accepted Storax answer, because he coded everything out without using the Error Resume. Nothing against yours, it's just that I prefer his.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Why not just iterate over existing sheets and compare their names? If duplicate found simply do not create the new sheet.

```
Private Sub CreateSheet()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Dim sheet_counter As Integer
    Dim check_duplicates As Boolean

    check_duplicates = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count


    For sheet_counter = 1 To WS_Count
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet_counter).Name = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1") Then:
            check_duplicates = True
            MsgBox ("Name already exists, Worksheet not created")

    If Not check_duplicates Then:
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("Sheet1"))


    If Not Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1") = "" Then
        ws.Name = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N1")


    On Error Resume Next


        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:AB").Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Yours works of course as well. I accepted Storax answer, because he coded everything out without using the Error Resume. Nothing against yours, it's just that I prefer his.

Answer (score 1):

I'm personally not a big fan of `On Error` statements, though it might be legitimate use here. However here is another idea, adjust to your needs:

```
Dim nom As String: nom = "Sheet1"

If VarType(Evaluate(Replace("?!A1", "?", nom))) <> vbError Then
    'Sheet exists
Else
    'Sheet does not exists
End If
```

<sub>**Note:** This would work if the evaluated cell does not hold an error itself. So maybe pick a cell you know won't have any formula.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and inputs.