# Looping through sheets to see if sheet name is already taken - Len/Left function in loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm having an issue with below. My code is basically a sorting function, where it pulls data from another sheet in order to give the user the correct view, however if the user selects the same product twice, my code produces an error since the information sheet is already in the workbook.

Therefore I simply want it to select the sheet, if the sheet is already in the workbook instead of running the code once more.

My issue is, that sometimes the sheet name will have more than 31 characters, which is why I use the left/len function. The problem is that it doesn't recognize the existing sheet name as

```
Left(Myvalue & " Case Types", 31)
```

and therefore just runs the code even though sheet already exist and therefore produces an error. When tabbing through the code with F8 I can see that the name should be same. Any suggestions?

```
Dim S As Worksheet

Myvalue = activecell.Value

For Each S In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If S.Name = Left(Myvalue & " Case Types", 31) Then GoTo Sheetalreadyexist
Next S

'Create New Sheet
Set ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
    If Len(Myvalue & " Case Types") > 31 Then
    ws.Name = Left(Myvalue & " Case Types", 31)
    Else: ws.Name = Myvalue & " Case Types"
    End If

Sheetalreadyexist: sheets(Left(Myvalue & " Case Types", 31).select
```

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59424032/9758194) to avoid loops or `on error` handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following function to check if a sheet exists or not

```
 Public Function sheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional wrkBook As Workbook) As Boolean

    If wrkBook Is Nothing Then
        Set wrkBook = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook - whichever appropriate
    End If

    On Error GoTo EH

    sheetExists = False  ' Not really neccessary as this is the default

    Dim sht As Object

    For Each sht In wrkBook.Sheets
        If UCase(sht.Name) = UCase(SheetName) Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sht

    Exit Function

EH:
    sheetExists = False
End Function
```

Then your code would look like that

```
Sub OP_Code()

    Dim S As Worksheet

    Myvalue = ActiveCell.Value

    If sheetExists(Left(Myvalue & " Case Types", 31)) Then
        Sheets(Left(Myvalue & " Case Types", 31)).Select
    Else
        'Create New Sheet
        Set ws = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
        If Len(Myvalue & " Case Types") > 31 Then
            ws.Name = Left(Myvalue & " Case Types", 31)
        Else: ws.Name = Myvalue & " Case Types"
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it solved the initial problem!
However I just tested with upper/lower case letters and then it produces an error. How can I solve this?

would a ````str(```` solve this?

Comment: I'd suggest to open an new post for this as it seems to be a new problem

Comment: Nevermind, your quicker code did something. Don't quite know why though. Now it doesn't present the error. Great job, thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Quicker version

```
Public Function sheetExists(SheetName As String, Optional wrkBook As Workbook) As Boolean
    If wrkBook Is Nothing Then
        Set wrkBook = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkbook - whichever appropriate
    End If
    On Error GoTo EH
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    set sht = wrkbook.worksheets(sheetname) 'will cause error if sheetname doesn't exist
    Set sht = nothing
    SheetExists=true
    Exit Function
EH:
    sheetExists = False
End Function
```